# Is boost asio and c++11 a good match?

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost-asio

A client of mine wants me to make a high performance, reliable server which receives datastreams via sockets. He expects it to be in c++

It's been a while that i was doing c++ fulltime so I've been reading up a bit. Asio seems to be a good bet for networking in c++, and c++11 seems like a great new version of c++ with a lot of new features.

My question: is it possible to use both reliably? Does it make sense? Should I avoid certain c++11 features like lambdas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd base "C++11 features to avoid" primarily on your planned target compiler(s). I don't see any reason to avoid lambdas -- all the major compilers already support them, and the they provide a substantial improvement in readability.

On the other hand, depending on the compiler(s) you care about, you might want/need to avoid things like variadic templates and/or braced initializer lists.

Comment: Another thing to be careful about is the support for regex, the library provided with e.g. GCC 4.7 seems to be complete, but some things like `regex_search` doesn't work.

Comment: @jerrycoffin gcc compiler would be my best bet right? (i'll develop on mac and will target undetermined(as of yet) unix box). Or is clang a viable choice yet? I've used it in xcode iphone development and it's hard not to get excited with its static analyzer

Comment: @Toad: gcc is certainly supported on more platforms. Right now, Clang is fine on OS/X, semi-reasonable on Linux, unusable on Windows, and hasn't been ported to most other platforms at all.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the two of them together with no issues. For things implemented in both Boost and the C++11 STL, it's your choice which to use. In most cases, it makes very little difference. If you use Boost, you'll be portable to C++03 platforms as well (at least, that part of your code will be if it doesn't use C++11 features directly).

Boost was carefully designed to be able to take advantage of C++11 features where they are available without having to provide a "dumbed down" interface or poor performance to support where they're not.

And if you need good asynchronous I/O, you need some library to provide it. Boost is pretty hard to beat, whether you're using C++11 or not.

If your question is "Is there some specific reason I wouldn't want to use Boost with C++11 or C++11 with Boost", the answer is no. If you need some feature Boost provides, like asio, and only need to support C++11 platforms, then they're a perfect match for your application.

Answer (score 6):

See, boost.asio is network library for event driven programming - lots of callbacks, C++11 lambda makes writing callbacks very easy.

Basically combination of C++11 and Asio makes it much easier to develop and would make your code much more clean and readable

Comment: Lambdas are also faster than doing callbacks via bind and certainly easier than writing custom functors for everything

Answer (score 2):

The asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011.html) specifically mentions c++11 support